# Recycler View gets empty when the fragment s opened again

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a recycler view inside a fragment
when I press back to go to previous activity and then come back, the recycler view gets empty

i tried putting adapter.startListening(); to onStart()
also tried putting stopListening() to onStop()

recycler view contents show when i go to the fragment for the first time or close the app and open it again, but when i press the back button and again come back to the fragment then all the contents of recycler view gets empty

Here's my code:

```
public class EnrolledAboutEditFragment extends Fragment {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mCurrentUserId;
private DatabaseReference mRootRef;
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelAboutEnrolled> options;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelAboutEnrolled, ViewHolderAboutEnrolled> adapter;

public EnrolledAboutEditFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRootRef.keepSynced(true);

    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enrolled_about_edit,container,false);
    mRecycler = mView.findViewById(R.id.f_about_recycler_view);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRootRef.child("Users").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String username = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
            adapterFunction();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });

}


public void adapterFunction(){
    DatabaseReference reference = mRootRef.child("Contents").child(username);
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelAboutEnrolled>()
            .setQuery(reference,ModelAboutEnrolled.class).build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelAboutEnrolled, ViewHolderAboutEnrolled>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderAboutEnrolled holder, int position, @NonNull final ModelAboutEnrolled model) {
            Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.image);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolderAboutEnrolled onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_about_enrolled,parent,false);
            return new ViewHolderAboutEnrolled(view);
        }
    };

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(llm);
    adapter.startListening();
    mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Have you tried to call `adapterFunction()` in `onStart()`? Does it work that way?

Comment: yes i have tried it but no luck

Comment: Have you used the Android Debugger to determine where the execution point is going throughout the lifecycle?  is the RecyclerView configured every time? Is the data coming from Firebase but the RV doesn't display it for some reason? Or is the callback never called? Are you respecting the order of initialization? This is the kind of thing you have to describe so we know what you've tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your setHasFixedSize() method.